# node js zerorpc crashes on windows 10

Tags: node.js, zerorpc

I have a windows 10 machine. First I installed ZMQ 4.0.4 from a binary file, then I ran `npm install --save zerorpc`. The installed zerorpc version is 0.9.7. Then when I add the line:

```
var zerorpc = require("zerorpc");
```

my app crashes and exits without printing any message at all. If run through `nodemon` it prints:

```
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

This must be something specifically related to windows, but I don't know what. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I wanted to add that I am also experiencing this issue. My environment is windows 10 pro 64-bit, node 9.1.0, electron 1.9.7 and zerorpc: v0.9.7.

Comment: I will further add that i have tested `nodemon`, the message you see is related to nodemon itself -- im quite certain thats unrelated to whats actually happening with zerorpc.

Comment: I started an issue on the zerorpc github page. Find it here https://github.com/0rpc/zerorpc-node/issues/94

Comment: After days of attempting to resolve this, I have opted to move away from zerorpc. @Mister_L, I recommend you check out [zeromq.js](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js) instead. It is much more stable -- refer to the [overview page](https://github.com/zeromq) for other languages.